# Python Dlib Segmenation Fault error on import

Tags: python, dlib

Whenever I try to `import dlib` I get the following error.

```
/Users/Llama/anaconda/bin/python.app: line 3:  4052 Segmentation fault: 11
/Users/Llama/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Can someone help me with this, I've been stuck on it for days and its vital to a school project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that dlib [1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib) is a Python module written in C++. This is a case where there can be binary incompatibilities, or it could also be a bug in the dlib module itself.

It seems you are using Python from the anaconda [2](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) project, how did you install dlib ?

You can also try running python with `-v` to get more info:

```
python -v -c 'import dlib'
```

Comment: The first way I tried was using pip install dlib but i also tried using using build from source using cmake.

Comment: ok, so what does `python -v` said ? how did you compile the extension ? did you make sure to link the extension with libraries compatible with your anaconda python extension ?

Comment: Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
import dlib # directory /Users/Llama/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib
# /Users/Llama/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.pyc matches /Users/Llama/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py
import dlib # precompiled from /Users/Llama/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.pyc
dlopen("/Users/Llama/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so", 2);
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: There was a lot more but only these lines seem to pertain to dlib

Comment: Wow I can't believe how I was able to fix it. Uninstalled dlib using pip and then with conda. Afterwards I installed it using conda again and somehow it worked. I have no idea why but I am so relieved after all the time spent trying to fix it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have this same issue. I installed dlib with pip and kept getting the segmentation fault. So I uninstalled it and re installed it by manually building the binary files and linking them (https://blog.stromich.com/2015/07/30/mac-os-x-python-ports-and-dlib-compilation/). I still got a segmentation fault. So I then tried re installing it with pip and continue to have the same issue. I have uninstalled and reinstalled all of the (I think) related modules and even unrelated ones. I'm not sure what else to do. Any suggestions?